# Class java.util.concurrent.Executors was not found

Tags: java, teavm

I'm trying to use [Awaitility](https://github.com/awaitility/awaitility) in JUnit test, but getting this error

```
Class java.util.concurrent.Executors was not found
    at org.awaitility.core.InternalExecutorServiceFactory.create(InternalExecutorServiceFactory.java:47)
    at org.awaitility.core.ConditionFactory$12.get(ConditionFactory.java:885)
    at org.awaitility.core.ConditionFactory$12.get(ConditionFactory.java:882)
    at org.awaitility.core.ExecutorLifecycle.supplyExecutorService(ExecutorLifecycle.java:57)
    at org.awaitility.core.ConditionAwaiter.<init>(ConditionAwaiter.java:53)
    at org.awaitility.core.CallableCondition$1.<init>(CallableCondition.java:42)
    at org.awaitility.core.CallableCondition.<init>(CallableCondition.java:42)
    at org.awaitility.core.ConditionFactory.until(ConditionFactory.java:860)
```

Anyone have experienced and know a fix for this?

Comment: What Java version are you using?

Comment: java version "1.8.0_181"

Comment: @xybrek: could you double check it by looking up `java.version` property before the crash?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] and the full exception stacktrace. Yours is missing the exception name.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question is that I am running the JUnit test in [TeaVM](http://teavm.org/) environment
and this is not supported by the *emulated* JVM platform.

Comment: You should adapt the question so that this information is specified, adding a tag and maybe mention TeaVM in the title. Or else this question/answer won't be usefull in the futur since this won't be visible in any search engine.